# UIActivityIndicator in xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiactivityindicatorview

I m trying out for the concept of UIActivityIndicator.In the firstView I have a tableView loaded with data and corresponding accessorybutttons.So when a accessorybutton of a tableViewCell is tapped then DetailsView is loaded.Meanwhile Im adding an activityIndicator when accessorybutton is tapped.

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(143, 220, 37, 37)];
    activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge;
    activityIndicator.color = [UIColor blackColor];
    [self.view addSubview:activityIndicator];
   [activityIndicator startAnimating];
    activityIndicator.frame=CGRectMake(140, 195, 37, 37);


DetailsView *detailView= [[DetailsView alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailsView" bundle:nil];
        detailView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
  UILabel *empid=(UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:117];
        detailView.Id=[empid text];
        [self presentModalViewController: detailView animated:NO];
        [detailView release];
}
```

Then in DetailsView based on the empid it received from firstView it loads some data

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(143, 220, 37, 37)];
    activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge;
    activityIndicator.color = [UIColor blackColor];
    [self.view addSubview:activityIndicator];
     activityIndicator.frame=CGRectMake(140, 195, 37, 37);
////loads data from service url and parsing is done

 [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
}
```

Until here it is working perfectly..I have a back button in DetailsView and whenever it is pressed presentmodalViewController is dismissed.

```
-(IBAction)btnBack
{

  [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

But now the problem is I can see the presentmodalViewController getting dismissed but the activityindicator which started animating when accessorybutton is tapped still animating.So how do I stop that animating activityIndicator when presentView is dismissed and display only the data of prevoius view.

Comment: In viewWillAppear of your first viewController just add               if (![activityIndicator isAnimating])
  [activityIndicator stopAnimating];

Comment: hey @arizah add activityIndecator in DetailsView class instead of firstview and set as a subview of it and when your data download from url or if you want to go back at that time just stopAnimation and remove or hide the activityindecator.. its very simple and easy to use dude...

Answer (score 0):

in `DetailsView` class in `viewDidLoad` method just add activityIndicator as a subview and start animating like bellow..

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(143, 220, 37, 37)];
    activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge;
    activityIndicator.color = [UIColor blackColor];
    [self.view addSubview:activityIndicator];
     activityIndicator.frame=CGRectMake(140, 195, 37, 37);

    [activityIndicator startAnimating];
}
```

And also `stopAnimating` when your data download complete or fail and also in bellow method add in `btnBack` method or `viewWillDisappear` just add this bellow code

```
[activityIndicator stopAnimating];
[activityIndicator removeFromSuperview];///Add this line if you want to remove from superview
```

Comment: just in btnBack method dude.. and also remove from superview see i update code after 1 minute

Comment: @ParasJoshi: No dude that won't work. He need to dismiss the activity indicator on the first view

Comment: @MidhunMP see here he also remove from superview the andicatore it means here dissmiss it and in your case its very strange that it detalview indicator stop in firstview?? very strange

Comment: @ParasJoshi: read his question and code carefully, he added activity indicator on `accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath` also he need to remove that activity indicator not the one in second activity indicator. Also what is the use of removing the second activity indicator when the view is alreay get removed

Comment: @arizah you can also add this code in 'viewWillDisappear' method of DetailsView class

Comment: @MidhunMP here dude.. see here its happen when detailview load after loading indicatore must removed right?? so when he back to first view at that time the activityindicattor must remove from it so this answer useful dude..

Comment: @ParasJoshi: what is the need of your code in second view ? He is already removing the second view using `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated`. Then surely the activity indicator placed on the second view will also get removed. This is not a good answer for the current question

Comment: @ParasJoshi: please tell me, how the activity indicator placed on the first view will be removed. When he use your code.

Comment: @MidhunMP ok mate see i'll complete the answer then u feel its good then up-vote me dude..

Comment: @MidhunMP now see what i want to say to arizah see the answer Updated

Comment: @ParasJoshi: still this not fully answer to the question read this section and `accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath` **problem is I can see the presentmodalViewController getting dismissed but the activityindicator which started animating when accessorybutton is tapped still animating.**

Comment: @MidhunMP i think its not here you also use flow of my code yes dude?? bcoz when he push in new control at that time in new control if he set activity as a superview then its work fine and easily remove right dude?

Comment: @ParasJoshi: right. But he uses two activity indicators one in first view and another one in second view. He used same name for both activity indicators. that cause misunderstanding

Comment: @MidhunMP yes dude so i just say that use andicator only in DetailView  bcoz its required only in Detailview dude right?..

Comment: @ParasJoshi I did as u have said but I m not getting it while accessory button tapped and when I click on backbtn animating appears..Should I remove it from first view ?

Comment: @arizah then just see use this in firstview paste this code in viewWillDisappear method [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
[activityIndicator removeFromSuperview];

Comment: see in FirstView I have added activityIndicator on accessorybuttontapped event and started animating.and in viewWillDisappear added ur code.then in DetailsView added activityIndicator2 and stopped animating after download is complete.I didn't add any startanimating in detailsview.Am I correct bcoz Im not getting the desired result

Comment: but why you not start animating the andicator?? and also here not use indicator in firstview dude just use in detailview like the flow of my code  dude..

Comment: Please make a final edit to ur code what to add in firstView and what in DetailsView..bcoz im confused ..if I dont write it in firstView accessorybutton event then how does it start animating when I tap on it ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20912/discussion-between-paras-joshi-and-arizah)

Answer (score 0):

in ViewWillAppear method of first view write below code

```
[activityIndicator hidesWhenStopped];
```

tell me whether it is working or not!!!

Happy coding!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Use following code

```
-   (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

  {

      detailView.Id=[empid text];

     [activityIndicator stopAnimating];

     [self presentModalViewController: detailView animated:NO];

       }
```

or in your `viewWillDisappear` of FirstView

```
 {

 [activityIndicator stopAnimating];

 [activityIndicator removeFromSuperView];
```

}

Answer (score -1):

In the `viewWillAppear` of **first view** add `[activityIndicator stopAnimating];`

```
 -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
  if (activityIndicator)
  {
     [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
  }
}
```

Comment: @arizah: you need to write it on the tableViewclass

Comment: Sorry I didnt get u ..where?

Comment: @arizah: yes. Means add the above code in the same class where you defined the accessory event method

Comment: Now I couldnot see the Indicator animating when accessrybtn is tapped.

Comment: @arizah: first view activity or secondview activity indicator ?

Comment: firstview activityindicator only .anyhow I dont need secondviewactivity to be seen